# Where is the schema definition of PDF index in SOLR

Tags: solr

All, I had succeeded in indexing the `PDF` file into `SOLR` with `Post.jar`. 
I can see the file indexed when I tried to query the query result .

[image]

[image]

But I was wondering where do thes fields like `id`, `stream_content_type`,`pdf_pdfversion` etc comes from . I tried to search them in the schema.xml. But not found them yet. Where are they defined ? Did I missed something . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the metatdata stored by `Apache Tika` 
In addition to Tika's metadata, Solr adds the following metadata
(defined in ExtractingMetadataConstants):

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Metadata
Documentation

> Metadata
>
> As has been implied up to now, Tika produces Metadata about the
>   document. Metadata often contains things like the author of the file
>   or the number of pages, etc. The Metadata produced depends on the type
>   of document submitted. For instance, PDFs have different metadata from
>   Word docs.
>
> In addition to Tika's metadata, Solr adds the following metadata
>   (defined in ExtractingMetadataConstants):
>
> "stream_name" - The name of the ContentStream as uploaded to Solr.
>   Depending on how the file is uploaded, this may or may not be set.
>   "stream_source_info" - Any source info about the stream. See
>   ContentStream. "stream_size" - The size of the stream in bytes(?)
>   "stream_content_type" - The content type of the stream, if available.
>   It is highly recommend that you try using the extract only option to
>   see what values actually get set for these.